# What is a 'rollback' in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, badges, rollbacks

What is the role of rollbacks for badges on Stack Exchange?

Anyone told me it's used for badges; then, how do I get this?

Answer (score 4):

Rolling back is the process of 'reverting' an edit (or several ones). Essentially, you're going back to a previous version of the post. You can only do this if you're the author of the posts, or have the [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege. You can do this via the [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/299911/revisions) page, which can be visited by clicking the 'edited *x* min/hour(s) ago' link above the avatar of the last editor of a post.

Its name is derived from the [rollback term in databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback_(data_management)); a rollback cancels any changes made in the current database transaction.

Your first rollback on a site gives you the [Cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) badge, but you should *never* rollback just for the purpose of getting a badge. You should do it because the edit made the post worse, or the intentions of the author have been changed.